# wrong behavior in Kendo 2013.2.716 using ServerSorting option

Tags: sorting, kendo-ui, datasource

I am using Kendo UI for a long while (months ago) and I built web app prototypes. Usually I use "serverSorting" and "serverFiltering" options to "true" as I do theses operations on my servers.

This worked fine until I began using KendoUI's last version (I am using kendo_2013.2.716 and jquery-1.9.1.min.js). Since that moment I realized Kendo Datasource or Grid (through Datasource, I guessed) wasn't sending field "field" in "sort object". Before now it was sending object containing { dir = 'asc', field = 'id'}, p.e., but now it is sending { dir = 'asc', compare : null }

Also, when I debug var "options" in 
 parameterMap: function(options, operation) 
I see it isn't containing "field" which I am trying to sort by (I attach a screenshot about "options" containing)

Also, when ServerFiltering is true, I noticed field "field" in avoid and removed from array and don't sent to server, so I must use another variable name as "myfield" or whatever. 
 
Is this problem familiar to you?

Thanks for your attention.

Kind Regards.

I would like add I tested adding option

sort: [ { field: 'id', dir: 'asc' } ]

in Datasource. This is sent to serverside accurately, *but* it seems KendoGrid does something wrong when it sends field name (in fact, it doesn't send it) in order to change sort options in DataSource.

Comment: The screen shot is missing?

Comment: Sorry, OnaBai, I have no reputation for posting images, but, basically  it was a screenshot from Firebug showing sort object without "field" field. I write down in text: { dir="asc", compare=null} instead of { field='date1', dir="asc" } as it was working in previous version.

Comment: I tested it with the latest release and I get field sent. Some suggestions... try removing your parameterMap and check what firebug says that you are sending, define transport read as get and most important define in your grid [sortable](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#configuration-columnMenu.columns) as true. Are you able of reproducing it in JSFiddel / JSBin? If you include your grid and datasource definition I might try reproducing it.

Comment: Thanks, OnaBai. I tested your suggestions and it remains same.
I am unable to post whole code because it has got too many dependencies and I can not extract this part only. Anyway, as you confirmed sorting works in new version, you helped me very much.
I will rebuild datasource and grid definition and try again.

Comment: Well, I finally found and fixed it. Datasource has not explicitly defined names for fields in "schema['model']" array. This didn't seem necessary before (p.e kendo v2012.1.515). Thanks Onabai for clues.

Answer (score 0):

The version 2013.2.716 has an issue with the sort
http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-web/grid/grid-sort-no-longer-working-in-version-2013-2-716-sort-is-undefined-.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this in grid definition

sortable: {
 mode: "single",
 allowUnsort: false
}